# LinkedList ADT pointer block

Tags: c++, list, pointers, tree, nodes

I am implementing a number of LinkedList ADT's for my compsci class and I'm running into the same problem on every one. The code listed below is a binary tree ADT. The compiler gets lost when trying to input data into the new nodes. The code compiles without any errors, but the compiler does not return anything, I think it's stuck trying to find the pointer. I come from Java so I'm still working my way around pointers.

```
#include <iostream>
struct TreeNode {
  //represents a single node in a binary tree of int data
  int data; //immediate data
  TreeNode *left; //left subtree
  TreeNode *right; //right subtree
  TreeNode(int in);
};

TreeNode::TreeNode(int in) {
  data = in;
  left = NULL;
  right = NULL;
}
```

The compiler can't seem to find the pointer referenced in these two append functions.

```
void addLeft(TreeNode *root, int newData) {
  TreeNode *new_node;
  new_node->data = newData;
  root->left = new_node;
}
void addRight(TreeNode *root, int newData) {
  TreeNode *new_node;
  new_node->data = newData;
  root->right = new_node;
}
//counts nodes in binary tree from designated root point
int countNodes(TreeNode *root) {
  if (!root) {
    return 0; //empty tree
  }
  int count = 1;
  count += countNodes(root->left); //adds left subtree nodes
  count += countNodes(root->right); //adds right subtree countNodes
  return count;
}
void preorderPrint(TreeNode *root) { //root first, then left, then right
  if (root) {
    std::cout << root->data << " ";
    preorderPrint(root->left);
    preorderPrint(root->right);
  }
}

void postorderPrint(TreeNode *root) { //left first, then right, then root
  if (root) {
    postorderPrint(root->left);
    postorderPrint(root->right);
    std::cout << root->data << " ";
  }
}
void inorderPrint(TreeNode *root) { //left first, then root, then right
  if (root) {
    inorderPrint(root->left);
    std::cout << root->data << " ";
    inorderPrint(root->right);
  }
}
bool tree_contains(TreeNode *root, int item) {
  if (!root) {
    return false; //if the root doesn't exist, the tree doesn't exist
  }
  else if (root->data = item) {
    return true; //item is found in the root node
  }
  else if (root->data > item) {

  }
}

int main() {
  TreeNode *root;
  root->data = 5;
  addLeft(root, 4);
  addRight(root,9);
  inorderPrint(root);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's not the "compiler".  It's probably better to say "my code can't find the pointer", or "the function doesn't find the pointer", etc.  Q: What is your debugger?  Q: Can you step through the code in your debugger, to determine the problem?

Comment: GNU debugger. I found out I had to initialize my new nodes with the input data rather than accessing their data, which helped solve this assignment

Comment: @seaneezy With that your code is far from being "fixed". See (The Rule of Three, Five and Zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `root` is not initialized. It currently has an undefined value. It should be:

```
TreeNode *root = new TreeNode(5);
... // Do whatever you want
// delete root and everything else.
```

Answer (score 0):

A pointer is just a variable that holds an address of an object in memory. When you define a pointer like

```
int *foo;
```

you haven't initialized it, so its value is indeterminate. That means it doesn't hold a valid pointer value that could be used to access an object in memory. To make a pointer actually *point* to something, you have to assign it an address:

```
int bar;
inf *foo = &bar;
```

Now `foo` holds the address of `bar` and you can dereference `foo` to write to `bar`:

```
*foo = 42;
// bar is now 42
```

In your code

> ```
> TreeNode *root;
> root->data = 5;
> ```

You try to dereference (`root->data` is just syntactic sugar for `(*root).data`) a pointer `root` that hasn't been initialized with or assigned a valid pointer value.

Since you want to create a dynamic data structure that grows on demand, you want to allocate memory at runtime. You could do so using the `new` operator:

```
TreeNode *root = new TreeNode;           // allocates an object of the type                                             
                                         // TreeNode
root->data = 5;  // is now safe.
```

But since you provide a constructor for `TreeNode` that takes an `int` you can write:

```
TreeNode *root = new TreeNode{ 5 };
```

The same goes for many other locations in your code as well.

Please remember that dynamically allocated memory should be deallocated when it is no longer needed:

```
`delete root;`
```